# Linux login failed while username and password correct (tty interface)

Tags: login, tty

Many times when I tried to log in Linux through tty. Although I've entered correct username and password. It showed "login failed" and didn't give more message. I checked the log.

```
/var/log# ls -al
drwx------   2 root root              4096 Jan 30 06:02 audit
-rw-rw----   1 root utmp              1152 Apr  9 19:33 btmp
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root              4096 Jan 28 00:58 cups
drwxr-sr-x+  4 root systemd-journal   4096 Apr  9 15:02 journal
-rw-rw-r--   1 root utmp            292292 Apr  9 19:23 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root              4096 Dec  7 10:41 old
-rw-r--r--   1 root root             75851 Apr  9 19:28 pacman.log
drwx------   2 root root              4096 Apr  9 14:28 private
-rw-rw-r--   1 root utmp             16896 Apr  9 19:34 wtmp
```

I'm not sure which file contains clues. Many doesn't give detailed explanations. For example:

```
# last -f btmp
root     tty3                          Sat Apr  9 19:33   still logged in
root     tty1                          Sat Apr  9 19:20   still logged in
root     tty1                          Sat Apr  9 19:19 - 19:20  (00:00)
#last -f wtmp 
username tty2                          Sat Apr  9 19:23   still logged in
root     tty1                          Sat Apr  9 19:21   still logged in
reboot   system boot  5.17.1-arch1-1   Sat Apr  9 19:19   still running
root     tty1                          Sat Apr  9 19:09 - down   (00:02)
username tty2                          Sat Apr  9 15:57 - 19:09  (03:12)
root     tty1                          Sat Apr  9 15:57 - 17:43  (01:45)
#lastb
root     tty3                          Sat Apr  9 19:33 - 19:33  (00:00)
root     tty1                          Sat Apr  9 19:20 - 19:20  (00:00)
# last -5
username tty2                          Sat Apr  9 19:23   still logged in
root     tty1                          Sat Apr  9 19:21   still logged in
reboot   system boot  5.17.1-arch1-1   Sat Apr  9 19:19   still running
root     tty1                          Sat Apr  9 19:09 - down   (00:02)
username tty2                          Sat Apr  9 15:57 - 19:09  (03:12)
```

I first met this problem when using Debian 11.
I installed Arch 2022.04.05 today, following the official guide carefully. I haven't made many big changes to the OS so far.  Both root and normal user may meet this problem.
But the problem stills.
I've created a normal user and enable it to sudo by

```
visudo
myusername ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

There isn't anything wrong with the keyboard.
The problem only occured in tty interface. Sometimes after 2-3 attempts, the screen refreshed and I succeeded in one more attempt.
This is a serious matter, because I may lose access to computer after any reboot.
Details:
Computer--ThinkPad S3-S440
OS--Debian 11; Arch 2022.04.05
firmware--firmware-linux;intel and amd microcode;etc.
loader--grub
boot--UEFI with CSM support.

Comment: Giving a user `sudo` permissions should be done by adding them to the `sudo` group - without messing with `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Is there no `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: @Panki. There was one in Debian, it showed "authenication failure" but no more details. There isn't any in Arch.

Comment: @Panki Having per-user files in `/etc/sudoers.d` will allow for more fine-grain control of permissions rather than give everybody who needs access full rights.